# Possibility of changing $interval interval on runtime - Angular

Tags: angularjs, performance, recursion, intervals

I need to change the interval value based on user inputs as following:

```js
scope.refreshEvery = 1000;

//run on startup every 1 second
scope.interval = $interval(function () {
    scope.refresh(scope.page);
}.bind(this), refreshEvery);

//onclick will change the interval to 2 seconds 
scope.onclick = function () {
    scope.refreshEvery = 2000;
}
```

I have seen few solutions for JS `setTimeout` with recursive but that will not work here specially from a performance aspect as its recommended to cancel all the timeout and interval with the scope destroying event.
Is this possible with angular `$interval`!

Comment: cancel interval and start new? why not

Comment: @PetrAveryanov i have a more complex scenario, its not only a click event, i just try to make the point clear